# Get Last Month Date In Flutter / Dart

Tags: datetime, dart, flutter

in flutter we can get current month using this

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var formatter = new DateFormat('MM');
String month = formatter.format(now);
```

But how to get the last month date? Especially if current date is January (01). we can't get the right month when we use operand minus (-) , like month - 1.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can just use

```
var prevMonth = new DateTime(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
```

with

```
var date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 13);
```

you get

```
2017-12-13
```

It's usually a good idea to convert to UTC and then back to local date/time before doing date calculations to avoid issues with daylight saving and time zones.

Comment: If you only want the month, I recommend using `DateTime(date.year, date.month - 1, 1)`. If you use `date.day` you risk overflowing for, say, March 31st. There is no obvious answer to "which day is one month before March 31st", and different use-cases will want different answers (but 3rd of March is usually not what anybody wants :smile:). To get the *last* day of the previous month, use `DateTime(date.year, date.month, 0)`.

Comment: nice explanation. I'll use it

Comment: How we can get last date of current month?

Comment: Create a Date for the first day of the next month and subtract a day.

Answer (score 15):

We can calculate both first day of the month and the last day of the month:

```
DateTime firstDayCurrentMonth = DateTime.utc(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1);

DateTime lastDayCurrentMonth = DateTime.utc(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1));
```

`DateTime.utc` takes in integer values as parameters: int year, int month, int day and so on.

Answer (score 10):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy), it used [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) syntax. See below

```
Jiffy().subtract(months: 1);
```

Where `Jiffy()` returns date now. You can also do the following, the same result

```
var now = DateTime.now();
Jiffy(now).subtract(months: 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am using this code:

String lastMonth = Jiffy(date).subtract(months: 1).MMMM;

Answer (score 6):

We can use the subtract method to get past month date.

```
DateTime pastMonth = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30));
```

Comment: That wouldn't work on the 31st of any given month...Also in February it could go back two months.

Comment: `DateTime createdAt = Timestamp.now().toDate();
    createdAt.subtract(Duration(days: 7));
    print("createdAt: $createdAt");` Not worked for me. Printing current timestamp, not seven 7 days earlier datetime . Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are pretty hard to calculate. There is an open proposal to add support for adding years and months here https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27245.

> There is a semantic problem with adding months and years in that "a
> month" and "a year" isn't a specific amount of time. Years vary by one
> day, months by up to three days. Adding "one month" to the 30th of
> January is ambiguous. We can do it, we just have to pick some
> arbitrary day between the 27th of February and the 2nd of March.
> That's why we haven't added month and year to Duration - they do not
> describe durations.

You can use the below code to add months in a arbitrary fashion (I presume its not completely accurate. Taken from the issue)

```
const _daysInMonth = const [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

bool isLeapYear(int value) =>
    value % 400 == 0 || (value % 4 == 0 && value % 100 != 0);

int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
  var result = _daysInMonth[month];
  if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year)) result++;
  return result;
}

DateTime addMonths(DateTime dt, int value) {
  var r = value % 12;
  var q = (value - r) ~/ 12;
  var newYear = dt.year + q;
  var newMonth = dt.month + r;
  if (newMonth > 12) {
    newYear++;
    newMonth -= 12;
  }
  var newDay = min(dt.day, daysInMonth(newYear, newMonth));
  if (dt.isUtc) {
    return new DateTime.utc(
        newYear,
        newMonth,
        newDay,
        dt.hour,
        dt.minute,
        dt.second,
        dt.millisecond,
        dt.microsecond);
  } else {
    return new DateTime(
        newYear,
        newMonth,
        newDay,
        dt.hour,
        dt.minute,
        dt.second,
        dt.millisecond,
        dt.microsecond);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a set starting point at the start of a month, you can use `DateTime` along with the [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) package.

```
DateTime firstOfPreviousMonth 
  = DateTime.parse(
      Jiffy().startOf(Units.MONTH)
           .subtract(months: 1)
           .format('yyyy-MM-dd'). //--> Jan 1 '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'
  );  

var fifthOfMonth 
  = firstOfPreviousMonth.add(Duration(days: 4)); //--> Jan 5 '2021-01-05 00:00:00.000'
```

or

```
DateTime endOfPreviousMonth 
  = DateTime.parse(
      Jiffy().endOf(Units.MONTH)
           .subtract(months: 2)
           .format('yyyy-MM-dd'). //--> Dec 30 '2020-12-31 00:00:00.000' 
                                  // endOf always goes to 30th
  );  

var previousMonth 
      = endOfPreviousMonth.add(Duration(days: 2)); //--> Jan 1 '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat('MMMM yyyy')
.format(DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month - 2)),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<DateTime> newList = [];
 DateFormat format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    for (var i = 0; i < recents.length; i++) {
  newList.add(format.parse(recents[i]['date'].toString()));
}
newList.sort(((a, b) => a.compareTo(b)));
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
if (DateTime.now().difference(newList[i]).inDays < 30) {
print(newList[i]);
total++;
}
}
print(total);
```

You can use this to fetch the last 30 days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

In addition to **Günter Zöchbauer** Answer

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
    String g = ('${now.year}/ ${now.month}/ ${now.day}');
    print(g);
```