# get exact day in every month in DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying make loop 12 times as months in year

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: (i * 30))).toIso8601String())
}
```

my code is worked correctly but it's give a different days like

If I run loop in today 10 Dec it will give me that

> - 9 January
> - 8 February
> - 9 march

I want a result like that

> - 10 January
> - 10 February
> - 10 march

Answer : I Found my answer of my question here in that package [jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy#-readme-tab-)

```
dateOfCreated = Jiffy(dateOfCreated).add(months: 1);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add days, when you need to add a month?

Comment: Try answers for this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54792056/3810510

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you add 30 days to current date, but there are months with 31/29/28 days also. So you should add month's length to get next 10th or else date

```dart
void main() {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      final lastDay = DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0).day;
      now = now.add(Duration(days: lastDay));
      print(now.toIso8601String());
    }
}
```

**[dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/d89c43bdfdc38d5cd55ddd073b79876e)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
final now = DateTime.now();
for(int i = 1; i<= 12; i++){
   print(DateTime(now.year, now.month + i, now.day).toIso8601String());
}
```

[image]