# Get the Month and Year X number of months from now

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am attempting to generate a PageView that will display the Month and Year related to the number of times you swipe in either directon.

**Example 1:**

I swipe right twice, so I get Feb 2021

**Example 2:**

I swipe left 12 times, so I get April 2020

I have attempted to create a DateTime.now() and subtract an integer of months, but I'm not having much luck. I have looked at various plugins like DateUtils, but again no luck.

I have been at what should be a simple solution for while now and would appreciate a guidance.

The closet I get is the following which requires me to know the days in each month which isn't ideal

```
(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 90)).toString())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DataTime docunamtion:

> Returns a new [DateTime] instance with [duration] added to [this].
>
> var today = DateTime.now();
>
> var fiftyDaysFromNow = today.add(const Duration(days: 50));

```
// adds 1 days

DateTime _future = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1));

//substracts 1 day
DateTime _tomorrow2 = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
```

Also this, [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54792544/13558035) ,define the base time, let us say:

```
var date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 13);
```

Now, you want the new date:

```
var newDate = new DateTime(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
```

And you will get

```
2017-12-13
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to increment or decrement by months, not days.

Comment: check my modified answer :)

Comment: You're most welcome, kindly consider marking at we an answer if it solved your question :)

Comment: Blindly incrementing or decrementing `date.month` won't work if `date.day` isn't valid for that month.

Comment: He's not interested in days, but month and year. Also, days can be accounted for easily. Scope of the question was how to subtract months besides using i increments of 30

Comment: And this breaks down if we're looking at the 30th or 31st day of the month.  See my video at "Proper Month and Day Arithmetic in Dart and Flutter: https://youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Y'all are going about it wrong.  Presuming 24 hours in a day, or 30 days in a month, is just wrong.  Here's how to always get midnight the first of the month, 7 months before today:

```
void main() {
  var n = DateTime.now();
  print(DateTime(n.year, n.month - 7, 1));
}
```

Just use DateTime constructors.  They **wrap around** just fine.  Works at month's end as well:

```
void main() {
  var n = DateTime(2021, 2, 28);
  print(DateTime(n.year, n.month, n.day + 1));
  n = DateTime(2020, 2, 28);
  print(DateTime(n.year, n.month, n.day + 1));
}
```

Which correctly shows 3/1 for 2021, and 2/29 for 2020, as it was a leap year.

Stop adding 24-hour days!  I've got a video that explains why.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usFSVUEadyo

And here's a video that goes into this with more detail: *Proper Month and Day Arithmetic in Dart and Flutter*: youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU

Comment: And here's a video that goes into this with more detail: Proper Month and Day Arithmetic in Dart and Flutter: https://youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU