# Subtract month returning 3 digit day ( for example: 347/12/2019) in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

if i'm tried to get last month date using mentioned code i'm getting date like **347/12/2019** instead of **13/12/2019**

```
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7));
  DateTime Date=DateTime.now();

  Future datePicker(BuildContext context) async {

    final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialFirstDate: _startDate,
        initialLastDate: _endDate,
        firstDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 50),
        lastDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 50),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
      setState(() {
        _startDate = picked[0];
        _endDate = picked[1];
      });
    }

  }
```

```
onTap: (){
 setState(() {
    _startDate=new DateTime(Date.year, Date.month - 1, Date.day);
    _endDate=DateTime.now();
    Navigator.pop(context);
});
}
```

[**SRC URL**](https://gist.github.com/gokulsundar188/de5daba69afb126ce65b0cf488591fc5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Last Month Date In Flutter / Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420559/get-last-month-date-in-flutter-dart)

Comment: @Gokul Sundaramoorthy, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @AdamStrauss yes tried that method, for this method also i'm getting same output

Comment: @sudo_kaizen i'm working on DateRangePicker, in this screen i'm placed option to select last 30 days data, for that i'm retrieving startingDate using mentioned code.

Comment: For me `DateTime date=DateTime.now();
   DateTime _startDate=new DateTime(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);` is working fine. Please give your full code here so problem can be understood

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy have you fixed ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no it's still returning same value

Comment: @Dev i updated the full code

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy so exactly you need to get date one month before current date . correct?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes

Comment: Kindly explain the exact need. Its really confusing with code as first you are adding 7 days then some ways subtracting a month. What you really want in startdate and enddate and is user picking range value between those days.

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy check my answer and let me know

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy Why don't you just setState(() {_startDate = DateTime(picked[0].year, (picked[0].month - 1), picked[0].day)})

Also, where is the implementation code of putting the value to widget?

Comment: @FederickJonathan i attached my full code here https://github.com/gokulsundar188/dart.git

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if what you are trying to do is to get the month before today's month

```dart
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime pastMonthFromNow = DateTime(now.year, now.month-1, now.day);
  print(pastMonthFromNow);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything correct, but a small tweak is required in `setState()`. Replace your setState as below.

```
setState(() {
     _startDate=new DateTime(_startDate.year, _startDate.month - 1, _startDate.day);
    _endDate=DateTime.now();
    Navigator.pop(context);
});
```

Check the gist here https://gist.github.com/ragu-swaminathan/4c2dd2f49f585397e67143d34707f7cb

Comment: Are you getting the same 3 digit date? Above snippet will work fine. Please check the gist here : https://gist.github.com/ragu-swaminathan/4c2dd2f49f585397e67143d34707f7cb

Comment: yes still i'm getting the 3 digit date, in console it returning proper date, if i display that value in a Any Widget i'm getting 3 digit date

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy Maybe it's because you don't follow dart convention about naming variable, you used upperCamelCase instead of lowerCamelCase. Just saying

Comment: @FederickJonathan I think that may not be a problem?

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy share the plugin that you have used

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy I have edited my answer, just try it and compare it with your code.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Yea, just saying. I also think it's not the problem but you are supposed to get a warning asking you to change it to lowerCamelCase.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan plugin means?

Comment: Date range picker library that you have used. Since there is no problem found in the logic , we need to check the output returned from the that library is valid. Sometimes date format may be different

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan i have attached src URL